# split the line by fixed width in awk

Tags: shell

Actually I have a XML file. below is the content of the file.

```
<charge_amt>1.90</charge_amt>

<charge_amt>-89</charge_amt>
```

I want to separate the charges (1.90) and check that whether it is negative or not. if it is non-negative, replace the charges with 0.

Output :

```
<charge_amt>0</charge_amt>

<charge_amt>-89</charge_amt>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: so, you're editing XML with `awk`? Doesn't really seem particularly robust. What does this have to do with fixed widths? Why do you have to use `awk`?

Comment: Can we do this any other way? Actually file is too large that's why i am trying to do with awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sed`:

```
sed -e 's@<charge_amt>[^-][^<]*</charge_amt>@<charge_amt>0</charge_amt>@g' < file > newfile
```

Note that this won't play nice if you have spaces in the text, attributes on the `charge_amt` node, or any other funny business. So be very careful with this, and use a real XML parser at the first sign of trouble.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo !! Can you plz describe the meaning of "@" and "[^-][^<]*". why u use it?

Comment: `@` is just a delimiter separating the parts of the regex. `[^-]` means "anything but a - character". `[^<]*` means "any sequence of characters except <".